# Is this writing of integration by parts right?

Tags: calculus, integration

For example

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx&=-\int_0^{\infty}xde^{-x}\\
&=-(xe^{-x})|_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}dx\\
&=-e^{-x}|_0^{\infty}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

I know the result is right, but what is a $\int_0^{\infty}xde^{-x}$? should I change the upper limit and lower limit of it since it is $de^{-x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$de^{-x}$ is notation that used in [Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). When $g$ is a differentiable function, $\int fdg=\int fg'dx$ holds, so it is preferred to replace the Stieltjes integral with the Riemann integral form.

You don't have to change upper or lower limit, because $x$ is not substituted. You are still calculating that integral over $x\in(0, \infty)$.